# How to go from tuples to a custom data type?

Tags: haskell, custom-data-type

So, I'm having this class about catamorphisms and what not, and I need to code the in of a data type.

The data type is

```
data Expr = Num Int | Bop Expr Op Expr  deriving  (Eq,Show)
```

and the function must have this signature

```
inExpr :: Either Int (Op,(Expr,Expr)) -> Expr
```

`inExpr` should be, I think,  something along the lines of

```
inExpr = Either Num (Bop something)
```

but I can't figure out the something.

Comment: What should be the type of the `something`?

Comment: I think something should be an expression of some sort... inExpr must return an Expr, what I need is to somehow get "(Op,(Expr, Expr)" to match "Bop"

Comment: It's just ``either Num (uncurry ((`ap` snd) . (. fst) . flip Bop))``, what's the problem? :)  (Courtesy of http://pointfree.io.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't just

```
inExpr ie = case ie of
  Left n -> Num n
  Right (o, (e1, e2)) -> Bop e1 o e2
```

?

Or if you like `either` function

```
inExpr = either Num (\(o, (e1, e2)) -> Bop e1 o e2)
```

Answer (score 6):

You are quite close. We can in fact easily derive the type of `something` by using a "*hole*" (`_`) in `ghci`:

```
Prelude Data.Either> :{
Prelude Data.Either| inExpr :: Either Int (Op,(Expr,Expr)) -> Expr
Prelude Data.Either| inExpr = either Num _
Prelude Data.Either| :}
<interactive>:36:21: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: (Op, (Expr, Expr)) -> Expr
    • In the second argument of ‘either’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: either Num _
      In an equation for ‘inExpr’: inExpr = either Num _
    • Relevant bindings include
        inExpr :: Either Int (Op, (Expr, Expr)) -> Expr
          (bound at <interactive>:36:1)
```

So we know that this function `_` will need to have as type `(Op, (Expr, Expr)) -> Expr`.

We can for example use a lambda-expression here:

```
inExpr :: Either Int (Op,(Expr,Expr)) -> Expr
inExpr = either Num (\(o, (l, r)) -> Bop l o r)
```

We thus "unpack" the tuple and the subtuple with a `(o, (l, r))` pattern, and then construct an `Expr` by using the `Bop` data constructor, with `l`, `o` and `r` as arguments.

That being said, simple pattern matching, for example in the head of the fucntion, will do the trick as well, and is perhaps easier to understand:

```
inExpr :: Either Int (Op,(Expr,Expr)) -> Expr
inExpr (Left a) = Num a
inExpr (Right (o, (l, r))) = Bop l o r
```

Comment: Very well explained! Thank you!